# How do I stop my computer from falling asleep when using a game controller?

Tags: suspend, games

When I use a game controller, my games detect it and play fine. However, Ubuntu doesn't seem to detect any of the button presses. After awhile the screen dims and I have to move the mouse to stop the computer from falling asleep. How do I get Ubuntu to detect the button presses so the computer doesn't fall asleep?

I'm using an msi Force GC30 V2 on Kubuntu 22.04.

Comment: If you're using full screen apps; `caffeine` maybe helpful.  It can also be triggered manually (when not using full-screen apps).